# for loop in the external method is not working

Tags: c#, for-loop, methods

C# program to write any word in following format:
given any random word eg: number of students
Answer: NumberOfStudents

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter few words: ");
        var sentence = Console.ReadLine();
        var Answer = Method(sentence);
        Console.WriteLine(Answer);
        Console.WriteLine("  ");
    }

    public static string Method(string sentence)
    {
        var words = sentence.Split(' ');
        string answer = null; 

        for (int i = 0; i <= words.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            var First = words[i].Substring(0, 1);
            var Rest = words[i].Substring(1);
            var Cap = First.ToUpper();
            var low = Rest.ToLower();
            answer = Cap + low;
            return answer;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If type this:

> number of students

it is returning only `Number` and not the rest.

Expected:

> NumberOfStudents.

Comment: Step through your code in the debugger, inspecting each variable, and you will see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Debugging will be much much faster then writing question here ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply replace those lines with this code,

```
    var sentence = Console.ReadLine();
    string input = sentence;
    string[] sentenses = input.Split(' ');
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(var sent in sentenses) {                
   s.Append(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(sent));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("  ");
```

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
return answer;
```

ends your loop after the first iteration. It returns from the method.
What you need to do is to have a second variable which you can use to add `answer` to it at each iteration after you have transformed it.

```
// before the loop:
string wholeWord = "";

// last line of loop
wholeWord += answer;
```

in the end you should of course return the `wholeWord`

Comment: Can you please show me in brief how should I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
public static string Method(string sentence)
    {
        var words = sentence.Split(' ');
        string answer = "";

        for (int i = 0; i <= words.Count() - 1; i++)
        {
            var First = words[i].Substring(0, 1);
            var Rest = words[i].Substring(1);
            var Cap = First.ToUpper();
            var low = Rest.ToLower();
            answer += Cap + low;               
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

Each word will be append to answer. Maybe a StringBuilder would be better here, but for now I think it's ok.